Fos elastic search configuration

Unrecognized option "types" under "fos_elastica.indexes.wg_subject". Available options are "_id", "_routing", "_source", "analyzer", "client", "date_detection", "d
ynamic", "dynamic_date_formats", "dynamic_templates", "finder", "index_name", "index_prototype", "indexable_callback", "numeric_detection", "persistence", "propert
ies", "serializer", "settings", "use_alias".

help me regarding this? Actually upgrading version then elastica compatibility missing and upgraded fos-elastica bundle so this problem araising please suggest me what to do?
here is my configuration below
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: {host: '%elasticsearch.host%', port: '%elasticsearch.port%' }
    indexes:
        wg_subject:
            settings:
                index:
                    analysis:
                        analyzer:
                            wg_subj_stem:
                                type: pattern
                                pattern: "_"
            types:
                subject:
                    properties:
                        name: ~
                        matches: { type: text, analyzer: wg_subj_stem }
                    persistence:
                        driver: orm
                        model: WG\WGBundle\Entity\Subject
                        provider: ~
                        listener: ~


        wg_category:
            properties:
                category:
                    properties:
                        name: ~
                    persistence:
                        driver: orm
                        model: WG\WGBundle\Entity\SubjectCategory
                        provider: ~
                        listener: ~
        
        wg_course:
            settings:
                index:
                    analysis:
                        analyzer:
                            wg_subj_stem:
                                type: pattern
                                pattern: "_"
            properties:   
                course:
                    properties:
                        name: ~
                        matches: { type: text, analyzer: wg_subj_stem }
                        schools: { type: integer }
                        titles: ~
                    persistence:
                        driver: orm
                        model: WG\WGBundle\Entity\Course
                        provider: ~
                        listener: ~
                        model_to_elastica_transformer:
                            service: WG\WGBundle\Provider\CourseModelToElasticaTransformer
        
        wg_tutor:
            properties:
                tutor:
                    indexable_callback: [ '@WG\WGBundle\Services\UserManager', 'validTutor' ]
                    properties:
                        displayName: ~
                        gender: { type: text, analyzer: keyword }
                        schools: { type: integer }
                        availableSchools: { type: integer }
                        graduationYear: { type: integer }
                        subjects: { type: text, analyzer: keyword }
                        categories: { type: text, analyzer: keyword }
                        organizations: { type: integer }
                        studentRate: { type: integer }
                        currentResponseRate: { type: float }
                        currentResponseTime: { type: float }
                        allTimeResponseRate: { type: float }
                        allTimeResponseTime: { type: float }
                        courses:
                            type: nested
                            include_in_parent: true
                            properties:
                                group: { type: text, analyzer: keyword }
                                section: { type: text, analyzer: keyword }
                        courseGroups: { type: text, analyzer: keyword }
                        courseTitles: ~
                        schedule:
                            type: nested
                            include_in_parent: true
                            properties:
                                start: { type: date }
                                end: { type: date }
                                type: { type: text }
                    persistence:
                        driver: orm
                        model: WG\WGBundle\Entity\User
                        finder: ~
                        model_to_elastica_transformer:
                            service: 'WG\WGBundle\Provider\UserTutorModelToElasticaTransformer' 

What is going wrong in my configuration?
